# Slick Slider slickAdd not working when I use an index

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

This is the line of code I'm using. But it's not working. According to the documentation is should.

```
var content = "<div>Some Content</div>";
var index = some_value;
```

This line works:

```
$('#slides').slick('slickAdd', content);
```

This line doesn't work:

```
$('#slides').slick('slickAdd', content, index);
```

This is the resulting markup when using index:

```
<div id="#slides" class="slick-initialized slick-slider" style="height: 197px;">
  <div class="slick-list draggable">
     <div class="slick-track" style="opacity: 1; width: 0px; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);"> 
        [NORMALLY SLIDES SHOULD BE ADDED HERE] 
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/           This is the plugin's site. I tried both 1.8.2 and now 1.9.0.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "_it's not working_"? Can you clarify what the expected behavior is vs. what you are actually seeing happen?

Comment: Clarification: Not working means nothing happens. No slide is added and no error is generated.

Comment: what is `some_value` ? Is it another variable or supposed to be a string?

Comment: It’s an integer with a unique value and the lowest value possible is 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is adding at a given index. Look at the below code to have an idea.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var slideIndex = 1;
    var atIndex = 0;
    $('.add-remove').slick({
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 3
    });
    $('.js-add-slide').on('click', function() {
        slideIndex++;
        $('.add-remove').slick('slickAdd', '<h3>Hey ' + slideIndex + '</h3>', atIndex);
    });

})
```

```css
.my-carousel{
  max-width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
h3{
    background: #f8f8f8;
    color: #3498db;
    font-size: 36px;
    line-height: 100px;
    margin: 10px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}
.js-add-slide{
    background: #3498db;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 48%;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  <title>My Now Amazing Webpage</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css"/>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class='my-carousel'>
    <div class="add-remove">
      <h3>1</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='js-add-slide'>add slide</div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please create a jsfidle. I fail to see what’s different in your code than mine.

Comment: If you try to run here does it seems to be working.?

Comment: I see now. Basically the method is meant to add at a specific EXISTING slide index as opposed to adding a totally new slide index.